# Prevent sifr on certain titles

Tags: sifr

I am working on an existing site which uses sifr. It was set up to substitute all h1, h2, etc with sifr. I need to prevent this from happening on just a couple headlines.

Unfortunately because of the timeline I do not have the time to change the sifr-config to be more locked down and then change all of the html pages too.

Is there some way I can add a class to an H1 to prevent sifr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `sIFR-ignore` class to elements you do not want to be replaced.

Please note that any sIFR-related CSS applied to the elements in question (such as `.sIFR-active h1` rules) may still apply.